Weird drop and erratic behavior with power-on latch circuit
I'm experiencing some weird phenomena with a circuit of mine. It's supposed to be a power-on latch using BJTs that further powers a boost converter and an LDO which, in turn, power some LEDs and an Arduino Nano. There's also an audio amp connected to a speaker fed from the 5V but it doesn't matter if its connected or not, the behavior is the same. See schematic:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
What is supposed to happen:
I apply power and it doesn't turn on. So far so good. I press the button and the circuit turns on. The 9V gets converted to 5V and 12V, respectively. The Arduino starts up and goes through its setup. There's not much in there except some pin and timer definitions. The Arduino makes the LEDs blink some defined pattern and as soon as that's done it sets the TURN_OFF pin high. Q3 shorts the base of Q2 to GND, turning off Q2 which turns off Q1 which turns off the entire circuit. Until I press the switch again.
What actually does happen:
I apply power and it doesn't turn on. So far so good. I press the button and the circuit turns on, 9V get converted to 5V and 12V respectively. The Arduino turns on and gets through it's setup part. Now is where it all goes to hell. The circuit never turns off but just endlessly loops around. The LEDs blink like they're supposed to at first but at some point in the sequence it looks like it collapses and then restarts. The 5V are not stable at all (on the multimeter), neither are the 9V (seems to hover around 6V). If I disconnect the LED strip (above Q4) the program runs through EXCEPT the circuit doesn't turn off as planned but also cycles endlessly. It's just that the voltage doesn't seem to collapse fully, but I still only get ~6.5V at the 9V rail (measured at the input of the 7805).
If I remove power and apply it again shortly after the circuit turns on immediately, no need for the button press.
If I measure the voltage across C2 after removing the power I still measure ~0.6V so that makes sense with the circuit turning on again after cycling power. If I drain C2 the button press is needed again.
I thought that C2 keeps the voltage at the gate of Q2 high so I added D2 but it didn't fix it.
If I feed the 9V line (junction after D2) directly from the bench power supply the issue is gone so I'm pretty sure it lies in the latch circuit.
Maybe the current through Q1 makes it drop quite a bit of voltage which pulls the (supposed) 9V rail down to 6.5V but the current drawn is roughly 45mA and at that level the drop should be at most 0.4V according to the datasheet (the value is actually 150mA in there).
I know I should just use a P-channel Mosfet instead of Q1 and I plan to do that but before that I would like to understand what the issue (or issues) is so as not to repeat it in the future since I suspect there is more going on. My guess is it's something pretty obvious and I'm just too blind to see it.
Also, if someone has a better circuit suggestion for what I'm trying to do feel free to let me know. It just seemed like an easy circuit in the beginning but has since inflated a bit.
Thanks in advance for taking the time!

Did you try simulating the basic latch circuit and testing it (within the simulation) to see if it operates under all loading conditions?

I did, and it seemed to work with some load resistances though I did not really test a whole range and only with resistive loads. I seem to remember seeing some drop and deeming it "as expected" but nowhere near what I'm seeing IRL. I'll simulate some more and report back.

On your schematics, never join 4 nets with a junction dot. Move the connections along so they're all T-junctions. Reason is schematics with small dots, or poor prints of schematics, can make it unclear if there's a dot there. So a '+'-junction may be two nets crossing over or really a 4-way junction. If you don't use 4-way junctions ever, the net connections are clear and unambiguous. It's a good policy, established long ago, and easy to do when drawing them. Thanks.

How long is the Arduinos TURN_OFF signal?

@TonyM: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the tip! I also changed it in the schematic above.

@Tyassin: Well, technically it's endless but I guess it's as long as the power supply of the Arduino takes to go out.

Ok yes I see. I think I would add a latch circuit. You could look up the classic latch made of a NPN, a PNP and two resistors

@Andyaka: I did some more simulating and it seems the voltage at the collector of Q1 starts falling really fast at a load of about 190Ω. At 150Ω it's about the value I'm measuring in my real circuit which corresponds to a draw of ~33mA which is the ball park of what I see on my power supply. That seems to happen cause that's when the base of Q2 goes below ~600mV. The only question that remains now is: Why?

@Tyassin: Isn't that what it is right now (Q1 and Q2), plus another NPN (Q3) to switch the circuit off via Q2's base? Or am I confusing it with another circuit? Or do you mean to simplify it to reduce complexity and thus error sources?

@ElectroBadger maybe use a boost regulator that has an enable input controlled by your MCU. Connect the booster input directly to 9 volts?

@Andyaka: Yeah, I'll give that a try, thanks. I feel like the root of the issue is something else though. I just can't get over the 9V being pulled down above a current draw of ~32mA. I mean the drop across Q1 shouldn't be this big with a current so low.

You could reduce R3 to 4.7 kohm and see if things improve.

MCU GPIO usually weakly goes high when an input, such as on power-up before software gets going. That could cause the cycle you describe. Try connecting 2K2 from TURN_OFF to GND.

It is hard to be certain without looking at some scope plots, but I believe that the pulse from the MCU isn't long enough. As the power goes down, the MCU resets and it terminates the pulse before the power is completely removed, causing everything to oscillate.
You could add a pulse stretcher, but this is simpler, assuming that your MCU starts up fast enough so a short push on the button latches the circuit. The S/W should set the GPIO to output a logic 1 as soon as possible. When the MCU decides it is ready to power down, set the GPIO to logic 0.
Edit: I agree with Andy, R3 is too large. And the 1k in my schematic is probably too low, 4.7k or 10k might be better especially if you have power constraints.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Sorry, I was out cold sick for the past ten days. I tried your suggestion and it worked much better (used 4.7k for R2). I think the issue that I'm automatically alleviating by using this is that the drawn current can't have an impact on circuit stability via Q2's base voltage. Most likely what I was seeing was feedback action from: more current through Q1 -> more voltage drop across Q1 -> more voltage drop across R4 -> reduced base voltage of Q2 -> reduced base current of Q1 -> more voltage drop across Q1 -> rinse and repeat.
